# kill setTimeOut in removed swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

//Following function is used to remove loaded swf

```js
private function LoaderKaldir()
  {
   System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent(0.50); 
   try 
   {
    for(var sts:int=0;sts<=20;sts++)
       clearTimeout(sts);
    removeChild(calistirilacakSwf);
    calistirilacakSwf.unloadAndStop(true);
    System.gc();
    calistirilacakSwf = null;
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    
/*    calistirilacakSwf.content.addEventListener(Event.UNLOAD, function() { 
     SoundMixer.stopAll();
     trace("silindi")
    } );*/
   }
   catch (e:*) { trace("loader kaldır hata verdi" + e) }
   try
   {
    efektserbesilkhali = target.effectSerbest; 
    target.effectSerbest = false;
   }catch(e:*){}
  
//following is belong to loaded swf
package 
{
 import flash.display.Loader;
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.*;
 import flash.geom.Rectangle;
 import flash.media.Sound;
 import flash.media.SoundChannel;
 import flash.net.URLRequest;
 import flash.utils.Timer;
 import fl.transitions.Tween;
 import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
 import fl.transitions.easing.*;
 import com.greensock.*;
 import com.greensock.easing.*;
 import flash.utils.setTimeout;

 public class a1_3 extends MovieClip
 {
  private var yolum:String;
  public var dogruCevap:String = "birinci";
  private var imageyolu:String;
  private var twn:Tween;
  private var twn1:Tween;
  private var twn2:Tween;
  private var twn3:Tween;
  var twn4:Tween;

  public function a1_3()
  {
   yollari();
  }

  private function yollari()
  {
   /*trace(this.root.loaderInfo.url);*/


   var yol:String = this.root.loaderInfo.loaderURL;
   imageyolu = imageyolu = "/17/1/1/";
   if (yol.indexOf("bilisselbecerilermodulu") != -1)
   {
    var sonrakiler:String = yol.split("bilisselbecerilermodulu")[1];

    var sayilari:int = sonrakiler.split("/").length - 1;
    yolum = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < sayilari; i++)
    {
     yolum +=  "../";
    }
   }
   else
   {
    yolum = "../../../../";
   }

   addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,baslat);
  }

  private function baslat(evt:Event)
  {
   removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,baslat);
   zeminleriYukle(yolum+"images/17/1/zemin1.png",stage.stageWidth/2-660, 250,yolum+"images/17/1/zemin.png",stage.stageWidth/2+40,250);
  }

  private function zeminleriYukle(yol:String,xkor:Number,ykor:Number,yol1:String,xkor1:Number,ykor1:Number)
  {
   var zmnyl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yol);
   var zmnldr:Loader = new Loader();
   zmnldr.load(zmnyl);
   addChild(zmnldr);
   zmnldr.x = xkor;
   zmnldr.y = ykor;
   zmnldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, zeminOzellestir);
   var zmnyl1:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yol1);
   var zmnldr1:Loader = new Loader();
   zmnldr1.load(zmnyl1);
   addChild(zmnldr1);
   zmnldr1.x = xkor1;
   zmnldr1.y = ykor1;
   zmnldr1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, zeminOzellestir1);
   var karmasik:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + (1) - 0)) + 0;
   if (karmasik == 0)
   {
    zmnldr1.name = "zemin1";
    zmnldr.name = "zemin";
   }
   else
   {
    zmnldr1.name = "zemin";
    zmnldr.name = "zemin1";
   }
  }

  private function zeminOzellestir(evt:Event)
  {
   evt.target.content.smoothing = true;
   evt.target.content.width = evt.target.content.width * 0.9;
   evt.target.content.height = evt.target.content.height * 0.9;
  }

  private function zeminOzellestir1(evt:Event)
  {
   evt.target.content.smoothing = true;
   evt.target.content.width = evt.target.content.width * 0.9;
   evt.target.content.height = evt.target.content.height * 0.9;
   nesneleriGetir(yolum + "images"+imageyolu+"1.png", yolum + "images"+imageyolu+"2.png");
  }

  private function nesneleriGetir(yol:String,yol1:String)
  {
   var nsnyl:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yol);
   var nsnldr:Loader = new Loader();
   nsnldr.load(nsnyl);

   nsnldr.name = "birinci";
   nsnldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, nesneOzellestir);
   //birinci görsel yani soldaki görsel doğru ise burası deger("1") olacak sağdaki doğru ise deger("0") olacak, nsnldr.mouseEnabled = false; kodu aynı kalacak;
   nsnldr.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {
   var img:Object=getChildByName("birinci"); 
    for (var i:uint = 0; i < numChildren; i++){ 
    if (getChildAt(i).name != img.name) 
    {TweenMax.to(getChildAt(i), .6, { blurFilter: { blurX:12, blurY:12 }} );}}  
    twn = new Tween(img, "width",Elastic.easeOut ,img.width,img.width * 2, 2, true);  
    twn1 = new Tween(img, "height", Elastic.easeOut ,img.height,img.height * 2, 2, true); 
    nsnldr.mouseEnabled = false;
    deger("1");
   
   });
   addChild(nsnldr);

   var nsnyl1:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yol1);
   var nsnldr1:Loader = new Loader();
   nsnldr1.load(nsnyl1);
   //ikinci görsel yani sağdaki görsel doğru ise burası deger("1") olacak soldaki doğru ise deger("0") olacak, nsnldr.mouseEnabled = false; kodu aynı kalacak;
   nsnldr1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function() {
   deger("0");
   nsnldr1.mouseEnabled = false;
   });
   nsnldr1.name = "ikinci";
   nsnldr1.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, nesneOzellestir);
   addChild(nsnldr1);

  }

  private function setRegPoint(obj:DisplayObjectContainer, newX:Number, newY:Number):void
  {
   var bounds:Rectangle = obj.getBounds(obj.parent);
   var currentRegX:Number = obj.x - bounds.left;
   var currentRegY:Number = obj.y - bounds.top;
   var xOffset:Number = newX - currentRegX;
   var yOffset:Number = newY - currentRegY;
   obj.x +=  xOffset;
   obj.y +=  yOffset;
   for (var i:int = 0; i < obj.numChildren; i++)
   {
    obj.getChildAt(i).x -=  xOffset;
    obj.getChildAt(i).y -=  yOffset;
   }
  }



  private function nesneOzellestir(evt:Event)
  {
   removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,nesneOzellestir);
   //setRegPoint(evt.target.content, evt.target.content.width , evt.target.content.height);
   if (evt.currentTarget.content.parent.name == "birinci")
   {
    evt.target.content.smoothing = true;
    evt.target.content.width = evt.target.content.width * 0.6;
    evt.target.content.height = evt.target.content.height * 0.6;
    evt.target.content.x = getChildByName("zemin").x + getChildByName("zemin").width / 2 - evt.target.content.width / 2.4;
    evt.target.content.y = getChildByName("zemin").y + getChildByName("zemin").height / 2 - evt.target.content.height / 2.4;
    setRegPoint(evt.currentTarget.content.parent,evt.currentTarget.content.parent.width/2,evt.currentTarget.content.parent.height/2);
   }
   else if (evt.currentTarget.content.parent.name == "ikinci")
   {
    evt.target.content.smoothing = true;
    evt.target.content.width = evt.target.content.width * 0.6;
    evt.target.content.height = evt.target.content.height * 0.6;
    evt.target.content.x = getChildByName("zemin1").x + getChildByName("zemin1").width / 2 - evt.target.content.width / 2.4;
    evt.target.content.y = getChildByName("zemin1").y + getChildByName("zemin1").height / 2 - evt.target.content.height / 2.4;
    setRegPoint(evt.currentTarget.content.parent,evt.currentTarget.content.parent.width/2,evt.currentTarget.content.parent.height/2);

   }
   ilkSesiGetir();
  }
  private function ilkSesiGetir()
  {
   var ikincisesyolu:URLRequest = new URLRequest(yolum+"sound/17/1274(1).mp3");
   var ses:Sound = new Sound(ikincisesyolu);
   ses.play();
   setTimeout(bkl,1000);
   function bkl()
   {
    twn1 = new Tween(getChildByName("ikinci"),"x",Strong.easeOut,getChildByName("ikinci").x,getChildByName("birinci").x,2,true);
    twn3 = new Tween(getChildByName("birinci"),"x",Strong.easeOut,getChildByName("birinci").x,getChildByName("ikinci").x,2,true);
    twn2 = new Tween(getChildByName("ikinci"),"y",Elastic.easeOut,getChildByName("ikinci").y - 40,stage.stageHeight / 2,3,true);
    twn2 = new Tween(getChildByName("birinci"),"y",Elastic.easeOut,getChildByName("birinci").y + 40,stage.stageHeight / 2,3,true);
   }
  }


  function deger(degerlendirme)
  {
   var p:MovieClip = this.parent.parent as MovieClip;
   p.sonuc(degerlendirme);
   trace(degerlendirme);
  }


 }
}
```

I import a swf file into main swf, when I click on next button to remove it and load a new swf file still there are sounds playing from previous swf when a new  swf loaded into main swf. `SoundMixer.stopAll();` doesn't work out. `System.gc();` also doesn't work. main cause is that I use `setTimeOut` to play sound. Even I remove swf, settimeout works after estimated time.
Any suggestion will be appriciated.

Comment: Some AS3 would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the manual: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#setTimeout()

It's said that `setTimeout` returns `uint` - `Unique numeric identifier for the timed process. Use this identifier to cancel the process, by calling the clearTimeout() method.`

So if you want to clear this timeout, simple `clearTimeout(sts);` won't work. You need to do something like:

```
var timeoutId = setTimeout(bkl,1000);
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

Not sure if this will work throughout swf files, but you can always insert any public method in loaded swf, which you can call from parent, so the clearing can happen there.

Comment: That is good but I have over 100.000 .as file which I havent used any id for any setTimeout ,Thanks

Comment: You need to use id if you want to clear the time out :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [`Loader/unloadAndStop` documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop()) if you use `Timers` instead of `setTimeout` they will be stopped.

For example, a 1 second timeout could be performed like this:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);
timer.start();

function timerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void {
    // do stuff
}
```

It is a bit extra code to do this, but you could wrap it in a global util function just like `setTimeout`:

```
package {
    public function doTimeout(delay:uint, callback:Function):Timer {
        var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay, 1);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent):void {
            timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, arguments.callee);
            callback();
        });
        timer.start();
        return timer;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
doTimeout(1000, callback);
```

Note: you may need to store the returned `Timer` somewhere, or else it may get garbage collected. I'm not 100% sure.

Another option would be to use some kind of global manager that can easily clear all timeouts:

```
public class Timeout {
    private static var timeouts:Vector.<int> = new <int>[];
    public static function add(delay:uint, callback:Function):int {
        var timeout:int = setTimeout(delay, callback);
        timeouts.push(timeout);
        return timeout;
    }
    public static function clearAll():void {
        for each(var id:int in timeouts){
            clearTimeout(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using `setTimeout` directly, use `Timeout.add()`, and when you unload the SWF clear all pending timeouts by calling `Timeout.clearAll()`.

**EDIT:**
You're currently using this workaround:

```
for(var sts:int = 0; sts <= 20; sts++)
    clearTimeout(sts);
```

This will only clear the first 20 timeouts that were set. This is very fragile. A slightly better workaround would be to loop through all timeouts ever started, which can probably be determined by checking the current timeout id:

```
var i:uint = setTimeout(function(){}, 0);
while(i--)
    clearTimeout(i);
```

This is still somewhat fragile: I can't find any documentation that guarantees the timeout id is in fact ordered, though that seems to be the behavior. Also, presumably once you reach `uint`'s maximum value it will loop back to 0. That's a huge number, though.

Also, if the current timeout id is a very large number, the loop could cause a hang. You could avoid this by only clearing the last, say, 1000 timeouts. All in all, it's a rather fragile solution.

Comment: I should have known that before ı started to work in this project, ı cant change the codes in side loaded swf, I need something that would stop setTimeouts when ı remove loaded swf

Comment: You're going to have to change it. A global find and replace of `setTimeout` with one of the timeout abstractions is probably going to be the easiest.

Comment: I will work on the code you suggest and focus on jsfl to replace setTimout if can't come up a better removing function I used                               "for(var sts:int=0;sts<=20;sts++)
       clearTimeout(sts);" to clear all possible setTimeouts anyway your suggestion is a very smart approach  thank you very much

Comment: The problem with `cleatTimeout(sts)` is that `sts` will be only from 1 to 20, while the timer ID is an incremental value, which means that after the first 20 `setTimeout` calls, the ID will be bigger than 20. So your code will stop working.

Comment: A slightly smarter way would be to loop from 0 to the current timeout id. I'll post a snippet in my original answer...